# Джава. Метод для выделения группы объектов по признаку

Tags: java

Я чайник. Есть массив объектов, как выделить из массива объекты, которые имеют общий признак (поле)? (например, человек - объект имеющий поля "имя" и "рост", как выделить людей у которых совпадает рост чтобы, допустим, вывести их в консоль?)

P.S: Наверное, я ужасно изъясняюсь, извините :c

Comment: циклом пробежаться по всем элементам массива. Через условие выбрать необходимые

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то ниже - примерный код.

См. метод `groupByHeight` и комментарии в нём.

```
class Human {
    public String name = "";
    public int height;

    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

    public static void groupByHeight(Human[] humans) {
        // Создаём мапу `grouped`, где ключом является рост.
        Map<Integer, List<Human>> grouped = new HashMap<>();

        // Каждый элемент массива помещаем в список, соответствующий его росту.
        for (Human h: humans) {
            grouped.putIfAbsent(h.height, new ArrayList<>());
            grouped.get(h.height).add(h);
        }

        // Пробегаем по всем ключам мапы и выводим список объектов с соотв-м ростом.
        for (int height: grouped.keySet()) {
            System.out.println("Humans with height " + height ": " + grouped.get(height));
        }
    }
}
```

Метод выведет списки для всех вариантов роста.

Если интересует только конкретный рост - можно его просто запросить из построенной мапы: `grouped.get(requestedHeight)`. Впрочем в этом случае можно и вовсе без мапы обойтись.